# Output inputted String 10 times JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, input, output

I am trying to write a program which will read a string (word or sentence) input from the user.

I have called a function for this with a button (**But a solution without a function would be great as well just in case**). The program currently reads the word from input and it is not outputting to the screen at all.

I am not sure what the problem is by looking at it (I'm a bit of a noob) but there are no errors to take into account.

I want the program to output to be on screen in an alert box if possible.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<button onclick="outputMessage()">Try it</button>
<script>
function outputMessage(){

var text = "";
var word;

word = prompt("please enter a word");
for (word = '0'; word == '10'; word ++) {
    text += "The word is " + word + "";
}
alert(text);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Thank you for your help :)

-ShadowMinion

Comment: why are you resetting the `word` to `0` before every loop?

Comment: Aah ? `word = '0'; word == '10'; word ++` ?

Comment: Im a bit of a noob, I thought that would keep counting the input work until it reaches 10 and displays it.

Comment: for ([initialExpression]; [condition]; [incrementExpression]) - https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want the word the user typed in, to be displayed ten times?

In that case you're doing the most part good. Only your loop is incorrect. See this page for some guidance: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    text += "The word is " + word + "\n"; // /n is a new line
  }
```

Here's a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/n6d5wpgz/1/

Comment: Thanks for this, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a little code snippet. This code will output the input 10 times in the same alert box. If you want it to alert on every iteration, just place the alert(text) inside the for-loop.

```html
<body>
<button onclick="outputMessage()">Try it</button>
<script>
function outputMessage(){

var text = "";
var word;

word = prompt("please enter a word");
for (i = 0;  i < 10; i++) {
    text += "The word is " + word + "\n";
}
alert(text);
}
</script>
</body>
```